# Deserialize XML (outerxml) to C# object

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, deserialization

Here is the XML that I need to convert to the C# object

```
<SEARCH_CTX xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="">
  <MATCHES>1</MATCHES> 
  <TBL>
     <Result>
         <ID>13373384</ID> 
         <A_ID>216190</A_ID> 
         <A_Name>Fujitsu Account 1</A_Name> 
         <A_No>10200318</A_No> 
     </Result>
     <Result>
         <ID>13373384</ID> 
         <A_ID>217129</A_ID> 
         <A_Name>Test account 3</A_Name> 
         <A_No>10200374</A_No> 
     </Result>
  </TBL>
</SEARCH_CTX>
```

I Auto generated the class using  XSD in the command prompt. Tried to deserialize  that to object with the fallowing code

```
 var reader = new StringReader(XMLString);
 var serializer = new XmlSerializer(OBJECT.GetType());
 var dA1 = (OBJECT)serializer.Deserialize(rd);
```

It giving me the error
   Message=Unable to generate a temporary class...cannot convert object[] to object

Comment: So...what is the problem, exactly?  Do you get an error message?

Comment: @YYY Yes it throws the error saying Cannot convert type object[] to object

Comment: Well there's your problem, you can't implicitly convert an object to and object array.

Comment: @Amicable How do I solve that. do you have any solution?

Comment: Bob, there is still something you are not showing us, I don't think.  Deserialize returns an object according to MSDN, so the cast you are showing there should be completely superfluous.  Is `var dA1` the place where it is crashing?  Or does it crash later?  Could you point to the line that it crashes on?

Comment: A few questions: what is `OBJECT` (how is it defined)? In your code it's being used as a variable (second line) and type (third line). What is it? Also, what does XSD generate (the classes)?